# SLE4442 unresponsive card

Tags: smartcard, pcsc, emv

I have a project which need to play with memory card. I need to read and write into the card.

My reader model is: Alcor Micro AU9540 (http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-HIGH-SPEED-USB-EMV-PS-SC-SMART-CARD-CHIP-READER-AND-WRITER-SUPPORT-ISO-7816-/172165900399?hash=item2815e3286f:g:zJoAAOSwDuJWxOcc)

The card I use is: SLE4442 memory card (I lost the link)

I do this on ubuntu with pcsc-lite and pcsc-tools

When I use 'pcsc_scan' command, it can read the reader model successfully, but unresponsive card. Things like this:

```
leo@leo-ThinkPad-S3-S431:~$ pcsc_scan
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.4.23 (c) 2001-2011, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.8.11
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00

Tue Aug  9 01:57:39 2016
Reader 0: Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00
Card state: Card inserted, Unresponsive card,
```

But if I use my own in-use bank card (I know it is not memory card), but things like this, it got an ATR response:

```
Tue Aug  9 01:58:36 2016
Reader 0: Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted, 
  ATR: 3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 13 00 90 00

ATR: 3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 13 00 90 00
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 68, Y(1): 0110, K: 8 (historical bytes)
  TB(1) = 00 --> VPP is not electrically connected
  TC(1) = 00 --> Extra guard time: 0
+ Historical bytes: 00 73 C8 40 13 00 90 00
  Category indicator byte: 00 (compact TLV data object)
    Tag: 7, len: 3 (card capabilities)
      Selection methods: C8
        - DF selection by full DF name
        - DF selection by partial DF name
        - Implicit DF selection
      Data coding byte: 40
        - Behaviour of write functions: write OR
        - Value 'FF' for the first byte of BER-TLV tag fields:     invalid
        - Data unit in quartets: 1
          Command chaining, length fields and logical channels: 13
        - Logical channel number assignment: by the card
        - Maximum number of logical channels: 4
    Mandatory status indicator (3 last bytes)
      LCS (life card cycle): 00 (No information given)
      SW: 9000 (Normal processing.)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 13 00 90 00
MASTERCARD issued by MLP (Marschollek, Lautenschl?ger and Partner)
G&D 12696-GDM-10/11 DEBIT CARD issued by BANCO DE CREDITO DEL PERU
```

With the compare, it seems problem is on the card.

I also guess if it is because the card I bought does not match the reader? On eBay, the details of the card like this:
[card selling page][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6v1o.png  It provides some models of card reader the card supports (some of the card support all the readers). Maybe my card does not support my reader?

Or maybe I need to do anything on the card first then I can get an ATR response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A card can't do much to become compatible with a reader, its the other way round. Note that [SLE4442](http://smartcardsupply.com/PDF/DS_sle4432_42_0795.pdf) is a *memory* card, which means the communication is synchronous and uses two-wire protocol instead of asynchronous T=0 or T=1.

According to [Alcor Micro](http://www.alcormicro.com/en_content/c_product/product_01b.php?CategoryID=4&IndexID=4) the reader chip supports two-wire, so your card may be defective.

Comment: Yes, Alcor Micro says it supports SLE4442. Then should it be a driver problem?

Comment: And I asked Alcor Micro, they said they only provide Alcor Micro chips to any other vendors and they are not the end provider. Other vendors can make changes on it. Should this be the problem?

Comment: @YULiu Translating a pseudo-APDU to two-wire is not done in a few lines of code, but is no rocket science either. The firmware of the reader is the most efficient if not only location to do it. If an OEM saved the effort, there is little to be done on the driver level. It would still try another SLE4442 first simply to exclude the possibility of a defective card.

Comment: As I know, pcsc and ccid only support smart card. Do you know whether SLE4442 is a type of smart card? Many websites says it is memory card. But when I search 'empty smart card' on eBay, most results are SLE4442 card. I really get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Got the very same problem with an Alcor Micro AU9560 chip, trying to read a bunch of SLE4442 cards.

It appears that, despite the fact that the chip itself is claimed to support SLE4442 memory cards, mine wasn't. I couldn't get the definitive proof whether it was the chip itself which was somehow “broken”—it was reading IC cards correctly, though—or if the support was removed by the vendor (who still claimed in the product description to support SLE4442 cards). Anyway, the solution was to buy a different reader from a different brand.

For those who struggle with “Card state: Card inserted, Unresponsive card” error, chances are, the card reader is simply incompatible. With a compatible reader, you are expected to get the ATR from both pcsc_scan and opensc-tool.

See also: [Card state: Card inserted, Unresponsive card](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/pcsc-tools/issues/29) GitHub issue.